# Set state based on particular element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, state

I have 3 links, I want to change the text of the link on click of the element, but it affects all the links there, when i click on a link, all the links change to `back` , but i want it to be only that link that changes, Please how can I do that

```
 class Apps extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Don't do this!
    this.state = { showing: true, word: false };

}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
         <div className="container">
            <div style={{ display: (this.state.showing ? 'block' : 'none') }}>A Single Page web application
             made with react</div>
         </div>
            <div className="buttons">
                <a href='' ref="login" onClick={this.onclick.bind(this)} >{this.state.word ? 'back' : 'Login'}</a><br/><a href='' onClick={this.onclick.bind(this)}>{this.state.word ? 'back' : 'Signup'}</a><br />
                <a href='' onClick={this.onclick.bind(this)}>{this.state.word ? 'back' : 'Members'}</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

}onclick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({showing: !this.state.showing});
    this.setState({word: !this.state.word});
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your links into separate components with their own states.